# Getting a Set-ExecutionPolicy error everytime I run a powershell script

Tags: powershell

Whenever I run a powershell script, I get the error:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting 
is overridden by
a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
execution policy of Unrestricted. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more
information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
```

This doesn't happen when I run scripts in Powershell ISE or run commands on the command-line.
Is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is written in the error message you can check with `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` all your policies. The more detailed scope level overrides the more general level.

In my case, I solved it by setting the execution policy on the process level.

```
Set-Executionpolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
```